# Glossaries: italic first use in text but not the parentheses for specific entries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra, emphasis

This might be a tricky one. I am using the `glossaries-extra` package to define a list of acronyms. In my document I have 'general' acronyms and sometimes 'jargon' acronyms that I would like to emphacize in italic.

With the present MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automake,abbreviations,nonumberlist,sort=def,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble[\acronymtype]{\glssetwidest{RMS}} 

\newabbreviation{rms}{RMS}{Root Mean Square}
\newabbreviation{usa}{USA}{United States of America}

\begin{document}

We often define amplitudes in terms of their \gls{rms} value.
I live in the \gls{usa}.
% \textit{\gls{rms}} also italicises the parentheses


\printabbreviations[style=alttree]

\end{document}
```

How could I define a command that puts specific entries in italic in their first use, but not the actual acronym between parentheses, while leaving the acronym list untouched?

If I use `\textit{\gls{rms}}`, the definition and the parentheses are in italic.

If I use `\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}`, all the entries are in italic.

Behaviour wanted:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is using categories. The default category is `general`.
Let's assume your jargon entries should be category `jargon`.

`\glssetcategoryattribute{jargon}{textformat}{texttt}` affects only jargon entries, but it also affects the short form.

Instead you could use `\setabbreviationstyle[jargon]{<style>}`, however that also affects the style used in the Glossary. Additionally it looks like you would have to define your own style for what you want.

Instead I suggest the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automake,abbreviations,nonumberlist,sort=def,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble[\acronymtype]{\glssetwidest{RMS}}
\setabbreviationstyle[jargon]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{jargon}{glossdescfont}{emph} % Remove emph in glossary by using it again

\newabbreviation[category=jargon]{rms}{RMS}{\emph{Root Mean Square}}
\newabbreviation{usa}{USA}{United States of America}

\begin{document}

    We often define amplitudes in terms of their \gls{rms} value.
    I live in the \gls{usa}.

    \printabbreviations[style=alttree]

\end{document}
```

[image]
As you probably noticed I'm using `\emph` here, since using it twice removes the italics effect. If you are using some style where emph does not use italics then this is probably not suitable.
`\glssetcategoryattribute{jargon}{glossdescfont}{textnormal}` Does not work if the description was in italics before.

Comment: that works like a charm. thank you very much